# Calling 'IsAssignableFrom' from an interface doesn't return the concrete class

Tags: c#, inheritance, .net-4.0

I am trying to return the object type of the class that implements the interface defined in the code below.

The linq statement only returns the interface itself, and so the console output is just:

> AssignableExperiment.IRule

Why isn't the concrete class being returned?

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace AssignableExperiment
{
    public interface IRule
    {
        void Validate(string s);
    }

    public class ConcreteRule : IRule
    {
        public void Validate(string s)
        {
           // some logic
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var ruleType = typeof(IRule);

            var ruleTypes = from t in ruleType.Assembly.GetTypes()
                            where t.IsAssignableFrom(ruleType)
                            select t;

            foreach (var type in ruleTypes)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(type);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should turn it around the `IsAssignableFrom` [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx). Because `IsAssignableFrom` works another way around as expected: `BaseType.IsAssignableFrom(DerviedType)` returns true.

```
var ruleTypes = from t in ruleType.Assembly.GetTypes()
                            where ruleType.IsAssignableFrom(t)
                            select t;
```

If you don't want to get back `IRule`:

```
var ruleTypes = from t in ruleType.Assembly.GetTypes()
                            where ruleType.IsAssignableFrom(t) && t != ruleType
                            select t;
```

Answer (score 14):

I hate the IsAssignableFrom, it is so nefariously written.

I always roll the extension:

```
public static bool IsTypeOf<T>(this Type type)
{
    return typeof (T).IsAssignableFrom(type);
}
```

Using this prevents insidious errant execution.

Then you could write:

`var ruleTypes = ruleType.Assembly.GetTypes().Where(t=> t.IsTypeOf<IRule>());`

Comment: There's only place I need it in my project right now so I'll leave out the generic helpers, thanks for your answer tho.